# consider 6 rows have been dropped, why is the range of index still the same?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning this [post](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=127bf6d6a4401a7b89566ef30d12fa0ebd90679f&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f70726f626d6c2f707970726f626d6c2f313237626636643661343430316137623839353636656633306431326661306562643930363739662f6e6f7465626f6f6b732f696e74726f2f696e74726f64756374696f6e2e6970796e62&nwo=probml%2Fpyprobml&path=notebooks%2Fintro%2Fintroduction.ipynb&repository_id=65924871&repository_type=Repository#jax)

This code is for Exploratory data analysis on Auto-mpg dataset.

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
column_names = ['MPG','Cylinders','Displacement','Horsepower','Weight',
                'Acceleration', 'Year', 'Origin', 'Name']
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names, sep='\s+', na_values="?")

# The last column (name) is a unique id for the car, so we drop it
df = df.drop(columns=['Name'])
df.info()
```

focus on this part of output

```
RangeIndex: 398 entries, 0 to 397
```

which will be

```
Int64Index: 392 entries, 0 to 397
```

after drop missing values

```
df = df.dropna()
df.info()
```

Consider 6 rows have been dropped, why is the range of index still 0 to 397?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop columns in pandas, the index does not reset. So the index will still go from 0 to 398, but there will be "holes" in the index for the records that were dropped. Run `df.shape` and you can see that the rows were actually dropped. To reset the index you can run

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.index
```

and you'll see the index go from 0 to 392 as you're expecting

Answer (score 1):

Pandas creates a new dataframe with some records removed.  It doesn't reindex the dataframe.  The result is a record with an index in the new dataframe correspond to the record with the same index in the old dataframe.  Indices of the new dataframe will correspond to the index of the new dataframe.  In your example, the final index has a range from 0 to 397, but it does not contain all the values from 0 to 397.  If the original index was vin-prefix or something more meaningful you would likely expect this behavior.

Before the dropna

```
In : df.index                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=398, step=1)
```

But after the dropna

```
Out: Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,
        ...
        388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397],
       dtype='int64', length=392)
```

You can get the exact difference with a `.difference` call between the indices.

```
df_before.index.difference(df_after.index)
Int64Index([32, 126, 330, 336, 354, 374], dtype='int64')
```